# How to retrieve the value of a DataTable column with an array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a `DataTable`, which I construct in the following way:

```
DataTable data = new DataTable();

data.Columns.Add("year");
data.Columns.Add("month");
data.Columns.Add("id");
data.Columns.Add("displayText");

data.Columns["displayText"].Expression = "Convert(year, 'System.String') + ' / ' + Convert(month , 'System.String')";

DataColumn[] keyColumns = new DataColumn[2];
keyColumns[0] = data.Columns["year"];
keyColumns[1] = data.Columns["month"];

data.PrimaryKey = keyColumns;
```

`data` is used as a data source for the `monthList` drop down list

```
this.monthList.DataTextField = "displayText";
this.monthList.DataValueField = "id";
this.monthList.DataSource = data;
this.monthList.DataBind();
```

Then I have an event handler, in which I need to extract both components of the key column.

How can I do that?

I tried to use `monthList.SelectedItem.Value`, but it contains a string `"System.Object[]"`.

**Update 1:** Here's the debugger's screenshot.

[image: Debugger screenshot]

**Update 2:** Here's how I add items to `data`:

```
var row = data.NewRow();

row["year"] = 2014;
row["month"] = 5;
row["id"] = new object[] { 2014, 5 };

data.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: I might miss something but what is a `monthList`?

Comment: @Arion `<asp:DropDownList ID="monthList" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: Are you sure that you run exactly the same binding code that you pasted? When I run your example I have `id` column value under `montList.SelectedItem.Value`

Comment: @st4hoo Pretty sure. Maybe I'm adding the items in a wrong way - see update 2.

Comment: Yes I was adding single int value as a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are trying to store an array in your `id` field considering that the same values are stored in the same row but in different columns, but you could extract the values in that field if you declare your column of type object

```
  data.Columns.Add("id", typeof(object));
```

and then retrieve them with

```
 object[] ids = (object[])data.Rows[0]["id"];


 for(int x = 0; x < ids.Length; x++)
     Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(ids[x]));
```

Comment: When I have a reference to `monthList` (`monthList.DataSource == null`  being true), but not to `data`, how can I access the other two int columns?

Comment: Do you rebind your datasource on the postback of your page?

Comment: That's probably the reason of your datasource being null.

Comment: After I call `monthList.DataBind()`, the data source is still null.

Comment: But the code that initializes the `data` variable is in the same method of the code that binds the DropDownList?

Comment: I realized that some of the code wasn't called when the event handler fired. I modified it and now I can access the data source. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that binding a column that contains collection of objects to DataValueField property of DropDownList is not supported by design(it makes `value` attribute of `option` tag to be set to collection type name).

You could try to dump collection objects to a single string value and use that string value as a key...

For example:

```
row["id"] = "2014_05";
```

**EDIT**:

Of course you may calculate this key value automatically using the same feature as you used for `displayText` column:

```
data.Columns["id"].Expression = "Convert(year, 'System.String') + '_' + Convert(month , 'System.String')";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set:

```
this.monthList.DataValueField = "id";
```

Therefore the Value property will be set to the value of the "id" column in your DataTable.

The "id" column in your DataTable is defined (by default) as type "String", but you've set it to an object array:

```
row["id"] = new object[] { 2014, 5 };
```

The column will actually contain

```
(new object[] { 2014, 5 }).ToString();
```

which is the string you're seeing.

You could try declaring the id column as type object[]:

```
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(object[]));
```

After which you should be able to cast `monthList.SelectedItem.Value` to `object[]` and extract your two values.

Having said that: personally I would probably put the two values composing the id into separate int columns.

Comment: I want the `id` field to contain two integer numbers. My question is - how can I extract those two integers from the `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem` property of a drop down list?

Comment: `data.Columns.Add("id", typeof(object[]));` didn't help.

Comment: If I have two `int` columns, how can I access them, when I only have `monthList` and `monthList.DataSource == null` ?